# How to generate Xtxt IntelliJ plugin project by an already existing main project?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, xtext

I am using Xtext to create a DSL. Let's say that I have created projects only for the eclipse plugin:

```
org.xtext.example.mydsl
org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide
org.xtext.example.mydsl.tests
org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui
org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.tests
```

Now, is it possible to create an IDEA plugin project after I have made some changes to the grammar? I think it should be possible, since the plugin is independent of the actual content of the grammar, or am I wrong?
Also, is it possible to create the web editor project now (not on startup?)

Comment: Xtext Intellij support is dead

Comment: @ChristianDietrich think Xtext 2.12.0 has full support forIntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio 2.0 Users .

Comment: The code is there. It is broken. There is no maintainer to fix it. And nobody from the community steps up to fix it. So Xtext idea is dead